# Bootstrap nav mr-auto not working as expected

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, nav

I have the bootstrap nav snippet below:

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar bg-secondary navbar-dark">
  <div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg"><a class="navbar-brand text-white" href="/">Test Site 2</a><button class="navbar-toggler collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarMain" aria-controls="navbarMain" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"><span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse d-flex" id="navbarMain">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item dropdown"><a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" id="navbarDropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">View Categories</a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
              <div class="container container-sm">
                <div class="row">
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="/categories/5cfe472022a68840484a3652" style="white-space: normal;">Category 1</a><a class="dropdown-item" href="/categories/5dc7ff6bac641e2548a9e279" style="white-space: normal;">Category 2</a><a class="dropdown-item" href="/categories/5dc7ffa1ac641e2548a9e27a" style="white-space: normal;">Category 3</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/pages/about-us">About Us</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/pages/contact-us">Contact Us</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/pages/finding-us">Finding Us</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item mr-2">
            <form class="form-inline" method="get" action="/search">
              <div class="input-group input-group-sm mt-1"><input class="form-control" type="search" placeholder="Search..." name="term">
                <div class="input-group-append"><button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Go</button></div>
              </div>
            </form>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/login">Login / Register</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
</nav>
```

I have copied their example on the bootstrap documentation site where possible.

I want to get the second `<ul>` pushed to the right so am using `mr-auto` as they do in their example however it's not working for me like it is in the example, I don't understand why. I even tried adding the class `d-flex` to the `#navbarMain` div but still no luck.

Even running through the values in the inspector shows everything the same as in the example as far as I can see.

Can someone tell me why this isn't working?

Comment: A little confusing because you reference the second <ul> but then in the code where mr-auto is...is in fact the first <ul>

Answer (score 0):

What you want from image you attached:
[image]

What my code produces to match your image:
[image]

Updated Code: [Demo on JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lub3m0ev/)

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark justify-content-end">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
      <a class="navbar-item text-white pr-2" href="#">Home</a>
      <a class="navbar-item text-white pr-2" href="#">Link</a>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn text-white dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button class="btn btn-disabled text-white pr-2" disabled>Disabled</button>
      <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark ml-auto mr-1">
        <form class="form-inline">
          <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
      </nav>
  </nav>
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Nothing is using ml-auto in your example, can you give an example with one ul on the left and one on the right like the bootstrap example?  https://imgur.com/t5wlFG1

Comment: @bendataclear updated the code and added an image and demo of what it produces to match your request.

Comment: I found the issue, it was simply an additional `navbar` nav object.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue, it was where I had used a container to constrain the nav elements:

```
<nav class="navbar bg-secondary navbar-dark">
  <div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
```

You can have nested `nav`'s but shouldn't have nested `navbar` classes, removing the additional `<nav class="navbar">` made everything work:

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-secondary navbar-dark">
  <div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand text-white" href="/">Test Site 2</a><button class="navbar-toggler collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarMain" aria-controls="navbarMain" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"><span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse d-flex" id="navbarMain">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item dropdown"><a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" id="navbarDropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">View Categories</a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <div class="container container-sm">
              <div class="row">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="/categories/5cfe472022a68840484a3652" style="white-space: normal;">Category 1</a><a class="dropdown-item" href="/categories/5dc7ff6bac641e2548a9e279" style="white-space: normal;">Category 2</a><a class="dropdown-item"
                  href="/categories/5dc7ffa1ac641e2548a9e27a" style="white-space: normal;">Category 3</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/pages/about-us">About Us</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/pages/contact-us">Contact Us</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/pages/finding-us">Finding Us</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item mr-2">
          <form class="form-inline" method="get" action="/search">
            <div class="input-group input-group-sm mt-1"><input class="form-control" type="search" placeholder="Search..." name="term">
              <div class="input-group-append"><button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Go</button></div>
            </div>
          </form>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/login">Login / Register</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Well yes, that's why I removed "container" in the code I pasted. It's bad practice and discouraged in the Stack Overflow community to post an answer to your own question if it was already answered as requested by someone else.
You didnt add anything that my code didnt already do for you.

Comment: Yes I did add something, I needed the nav contrained in the container. Your answer didn't lead me to discover the issue, it was basically another working sample where I already had a working sample from the bootstrap documentation.